# Use multiple tee commands redirections in a watch call

Tags: bash, watch, tee

The following command processes the output of the pipe twice by using `tee`:

```sh
echo -e "ALPHA\nBRAVO" | tee >(head -n 1) >(tail) >/dev/null
```

As expected it outputs:

```
ALPHA
ALPHA
BRAVO
```

When trying to call it with watch like this:

```sh
watch 'echo -e "ALPHA\nBRAVO" | tee >(head -n 1) >(tail) >/dev/null'
```

It returns:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `echo -e "ALPHA\nBRAVO" | tee >(head -n 1) >(tail) >/dev/null'
```

How should I escape my command to use it with watch?

Comment: Tested on GNU Bash 4.2.46 and GNU Bash 5.0.16. I observed the same behavior with both.

Comment: `sh` is usually not `bash`.

Comment: This works but it's not elegant: `watch bash -c '"echo -e "ALPHA\\\nBRAVO" | tee >(head -n 1) >(tail) >/dev/null"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process substitutions are an extension, not all sh implementations support them. You can use redirections to circumvent this restriction though. Like

```
watch '{ { printf '\''ALPHA\nBRAVO\n'\'' |
           tee /proc/self/fd/3 |
           head -n 1 >&4
         } 3>&1 | tail >&4
       } 4>&1'
```

Just note that this is no more portable than doing `watch 'bash -c ...'`.